# quisiera saber cual es error de este codigo

Tags: angular

```
export class RegistroService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) { }
   
  Envioregistro(form: any): void {
    swal({
      title: 'Espera',
      text: 'Procesando',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      onOpen: () => {
        swal.showLoading()
      }
    })
    debugger
    this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'api/registro/ValidarRegistroAsync/', form).subscribe((d: boolean) => { 
      
      if (d) {
        swal({
          text: "El registro ha sido enviado, recibirás un correo con las credenciales de ingreso en cuanto validemos la información.",
          type: "success",
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#D7405D"
        })
      } else {
        swal({
          text: "El correo indicado no se encuentra registrado.",
          type: "error",
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#D7405D"
        })
      }
      
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: y que es lo que no te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class RegistroService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public router: Router) { }

Envioregistro(form: any): void {
swal({
  title: 'Espera',
  text: 'Procesando',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  onOpen: () => {
    swal.showLoading()
  }
})
debugger
this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'api/registro/ValidarRegistroAsync/', form).subscribe((d: boolean) => {
  
  if (d) {
    swal({
      text: "El registro ha sido enviado, recibirás un correo con las credenciales de ingreso en cuanto validemos la información.",
      type: "success",
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#D7405D"
    })
  } else {
    swal({
      text: "El correo indicado no se encuentra registrado.",
      type: "error",
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#D7405D"
    })
  }
  
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
})
```

}
}**

Comment: hola maría, te recomiendo que leas [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que puedas mejorar tu respuesta y asi poder ayudar de manera contreta a la hora de enfrentar un problema, saludos